# How can i connect pyRserve with Python

Tags: python, r, rserve, pyrserve

i need to connect pyRserve in iPython, but there is an error when i try to connect it. This is the error.

```
conn = pyRserve.connect()
```

And this is what i get:

```
RConnectionRefused: Connection denied, server not reachable or not accepting connections.
```

In the pyrserve manual are and advice to correct this, but i don't understand what i need to do. This is the advice (Note)

Note When a remote connection to Rserve should be opened, and pyRserve cannot connect to it, most likely Rserve only listens to it’s own internal network connection. To force Rserve accepting connections from other machines create a file called /etc/Rserv.conf and add at least the following line: remote enable
Then restart Rserve.

So, i need to know how to implement the note and connect the Rserve in python

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 5):

In R (using 3.3.2)

```
install.packages(‘Rserve’)
library(Rserve)
Rserve()    # the actual server you will be calling from python
```

After running Rserve() you should see the following which indicates R server is running:
Starting Rserve...
"C:\Users\bkeith\Desktop\R-33~1.2\library\Rserve\libs\x64\Rserve.exe"

---

In Python

```
import pyReserve
conn = pyRserve.connect()  # the connection to R

print conn
>> <Handle to Rserve on localhost:####>
```

Once this prints, you’re good to start using the library.

---

Don’t forget to close your connection, to check it you can use conn.isClosed:

```
conn.shutdown()
```

---

Here’s some examples from the library:

Ex.1 – basic syntax

```
conn.eval(‘2+4’) #basic eval
>> 6.0
```

Ex.2 – list from python to R

```
a = [1,2,3,4]   #python list
conn.r.a = a    #the R variable is named a as well 
print conn.r.a 
>>[1,2,3,4]     #the R list is now in python as well
```

Ex.3 – Function in R

```
conn.voidEval(‘two <- function(x){ x * 2}’) #declare the function
conn.eval(‘two(9)’)   #use the function
>> 18.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue with you before and was able to solve it by installing [Rserve](https://rforge.net/Rserve/files/), make sure you download the file from their website and run the codes below:

```
R CMD INSTALL [Rserve_1.8-0.tar.gz] #put in the file name
```

And then when running this in the terminal:

```
R CMD Rserve
```

There should be messages indicating that r is in daemon mode, and then running conn = pyRserve.connect() should be no problem from there.